# NodeJS SimpleSMTP server NOT make authentification

Tags: node.js, smtp, authorization

I try to use NodeJS SimpleSMTP. Get source from GIT ([NodeJS SimpleSMTP](https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp))
And try add auth into smtp. My code is:

```
var SMTP_PORT = 2000;
var smtp = simplesmtp.createServer({debug:true, enableAuthentication:true});

smtp.listen(SMTP_PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});

smtp.on("authorizeUser", function(connection, username, password, callback){
    callback(null, true );
});

smtp.on("startData", function(connection){
    console.log("Message from:", connection.from);
    console.log("Message to:", connection.to);
});
smtp.on("data", function(connection, chunk){

});

smtp.on("dataReady", function(connection, callback){
    console.log("Incoming message saved to /tmp/message.txt");
    callback(null, "ABC1"); // ABC1 is the queue id to be advertised to the client
});
```

And for test I write simple client on Python:

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost',2000)
smtpObj.set_debuglevel(1)
smtpObj.login('aaa', 'bbb')
sender="sender@email.com"
toemail = "recv@email.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "my subj"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = "recv.email.com"
msg.attach(MIMEText("Hello world!",'html'))
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, [toemail], msg.as_string())
```

If I comment **smtpObj.login('aaa', 'bbb')** everything is OK, but I need auth user before send email. For auth in Simple SMTP I should use event **authorizeUser** and option **enableAuthentication:true**.

What I do wrong? Why server is not make authentification.

My logs:

Python with show debug info:

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-mypc at your service, [127.0.0.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250 STARTTLS\r\n' 
reply: retcode (250); Msg: mypc at your service, [127.0.0.1]
8BITMIME
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
STARTTLS
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/atlete/work/python/smtptest/src/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    server.login("aaa", "bbb")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 576, in login
raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

NodeJS debug info:

```
CONNECTION FROM 127.0.0.1
Connection from 127.0.0.1
OUT: "220 mypc ESMTP node.js simplesmtp"
COMMAND: ehlo [127.0.1.1]
OUT: "250-mypc at your service, [127.0.0.1]
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 STARTTLS"
Connection closed to 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: when I add options secureConnection: true, - AUTH is worked, but only when I init client like smtplib.SMTP_SSL('localhost',2000)

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say without seeing the SMTP logs (set simplesmtp `debug:true`), but you might check that the python auth method, i.e. LOGIN, matches what you set in the simplesmtp options.